# using java for loop with user input to make custom diamond

Tags: java, for-loop

I am looking to make a diamond like this:

n=2

```
 *
*$*
 *
```

n=3

```
    *
   *$*
  *$*$*
   *$*
    *
```

n=4

```
    *
   *$*
  *$*$*
 *$*$*$*
  *$*$*
   *$*
    *
```

I can get the diamond with just `*` but cannot figure out how to add the `$` in the mix

My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ForNestedDemo
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input number of lines:");
        int i = 0, j, k, n;
        n = scan.nextInt();

        for (k = 1; k <= (n + 1) / 2; k++) {
            for (i = 0; i < n - k; i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                System.out.print("*$ ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        for (k = ((n + 1) / 2); k < n; k++) {
            for (i = 1; i < k; i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (j = 0; j < n - k; j++) {
                System.out.print(" *");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you upload your code for a diamond of all `*` for comparison?

Comment: Pshemo, i am an extreme novice, would you provide an example of what you are talking about, I have used counter to count loops but not sure how to implement it into what you are talking about

Comment: @Alden, yes i can create a diamond using this code, but I cannot figure out how to add the $

Comment: @J.b.Daniel That's good, but the code in your question does not create a diamond. Could you add to your question a copy of the version of your code that creates the diamond?

Comment: Is your example consistent with the code? You prompt for a number of lines but in your example n=2 has 3 lines.

Comment: `n` is the number of stars at the mid point @ChiefTwoPencils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that @GhostCat is the easiest way to go, but just for fun I figured it out using your way.

```
for (k = 1; k < (n + 1); k++) {
    for (i = 0; i < n - k; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        if(j == 0)
            if(k == n+1)
                System.out.print("*");
            else
                System.out.print(" *");
        else{
            System.out.print("$*");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

for (k = 1; k < n; k++) {
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (j = 0; j < n - k; j++) {
        if(j == 0)
            if(k == n+1)
                System.out.print("*");
            else
                System.out.print(" *");
        else{
            System.out.print("$*");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

I have fixed some of your errors and added some checks in there also.

The logic I have in place is:

1. If you are the first character, are you the middle row (`k == n+1`), if so, only print `*`, otherwise print `_*`.
2. If you are not the first character, print `$*`.

After that I just simply took my logic and pasted it down below in your `lower half` loop.

Comment: I see what you did, i honestly did not think of using an if/else statement inside of a nested for loop, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

A simply way would be: instead of directly *printing* those "patterns", push them into string variables first - without thinking about $ signs. Just put the required spaces and *s into those strings.

Like:

```
"  *"
" **"
"***"
```

Then, take those strings, and build the final strings from them: walk through each string, and when you find that str[index] and str[index+1] are `'*'` you simply put `"*$"` into your result string (otherwise you just copy the character at index).

Using that algorithm, the above strings turn into

```
"  *"
" *$*"
"*$*$*"
```

And finally, you simply *copy** the **upper** lines down!

For the record: of course there are easy solutions that create the whole output in one shoot. But: you already got the loops in place that build lines that just miss the $ chars. So you *can* use my approach go get from your current code to a working solution easily.

Comment: I have to use for loops to make the diamond

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as follows:
1. first print spaces
2. then print alternate '*' and '$' as per the order of the line.

```
public void printDiamonds(int n) {
    //print the top part
    for (int i = n-1; i > 0 ; i--) {
        printDiamondLine(n, i);
    }
    //print the bottom part
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printDiamondLine(n, i);
}

private void printDiamondLine(int n, int i) {
    // i denotes the number of preceding spaces per line
    for (int j=i; j>0; j--)
        System.out.print(" ");
    // print alternate * and $
    for (int k=2*(n-i)-1; k>0; k--)
        if (k%2==0)
            System.out.print("$");
        else
            System.out.print("*");

    System.out.println(); //print a new line at the end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems like homework, I normally wouldn't give the full code. But, the cat's out of the bag.

I would try to think of things in a simple mathematical manner and carefully look at the relationships between spaces, `*`s, and `$`s. When you do the code may come a little easier to write, simple, *and cleaner*.

1. There are always as many `*`s in a row as the row number
2. There are always one less as many `$`s as there are `*`s
3. There are always `n - rowNum` spaces in a row precedings the first character
4. There is a top, middle, and bottom to the shape based on these characteristics

Given that, I would start by writing a solution that would be easy to debug and very clean. The interesting part of my `main` would reflect the characteristics of the shape listed above:

```
printTop(1, 1, n);
printMiddle(n);
printBottom(n - 1, n - 1, n);
```

These methods would be defined as follows:

```
public static void printTop(int i, int j, int n) {
    for (; n - j > 0; ++i, ++j) {
        printLine(n - j, i);
    }
}

public static void printMiddle(int stars) {
    printLine(0, stars);
}

public static void printBottom(int i, int j, int n) {
    for (; i >= 0; --i, --j) {
        printLine(n - j, i);
    }
}
```

The `printLine()` method prints a line/row of the shape given a number of spaces and `*`s. This is the part I would normally leave out but...

```
public static void printLine(int spaces, int stars) {
    printSpace(spaces);
    for (int i = 1; i <= (2 * stars - 1); ++i) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print('$');
        } else {
            System.out.print('*');
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I'm certain you can figure out what `printSpace()` is doing.

The benefit of this approach is it leads you towards what is inevitably going to be a primary goal of yours: decompose and modularize your code. This will become increasingly important as solutions become more complex. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 2;
    int mid = (int) Math.ceil((n+n-1)/2.0);
    String[] stringArray = new String[n];


    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int j = 2*i+1; j > 0; j--) {
            if(j%2 == 0)
                sb.append("$");
            else
                sb.append("*");
        }
        stringArray[i] = sb.toString();
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        for(int j = mid - stringArray[i].length()/2; j >0 ;j--) {
            System.out.print(" ");              
        }
        System.out.print(stringArray[i] + "\n");            
    }

    for(int i = n-2 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        for(int j = mid - stringArray[i].length()/2; j >0 ;j--) {
            System.out.print(" ");              
        }
        System.out.print(stringArray[i] + "\n");            
    }
}
```

Here you go. This code is not optimized in any way. Hope this gives you a general idea.

Comment: -1 This answer makes no attempt to address OP's code, and you provide no explanation to help OP, a self-proclaimed novice, understand how your code works.